# ryu (SDN) traffic controller from (example) Host 1

Tags: python, linux, mininet, sdn, ryu

I created a simple network in the `mininet` environment with the following command:

```
$ sudo mn --topo single,3 --mac --controller remote --switch ovsk
```

I want use `RYU CONTROLLER` to calculate bandwidth traffic on special port of switch. I'm thinking of using an `OFPEVENTPacketIn` event for the incoming packet, but I do not any idea for out coming packet form port.

My code:

```
from operator import attrgetter
from ryu.app import simple_switch_13
from ryu.controller import ofp_event
from ryu.controller.handler import MAIN_DISPATCHER, DEAD_DISPATCHER
from ryu.controller.handler import set_ev_cls
from ryu.lib import hub

class SimpleMonitor(simple_switch_13.SimpleSwitch13):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SimpleMonitor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.datapaths = {}
        self.monitor_thread = hub.spawn(self._monitor)

    @set_ev_cls(ofp_event.EventOFPStateChange,
                [MAIN_DISPATCHER, DEAD_DISPATCHER])
    def _state_change_handler1(self, ev):
        datapath = ev.datapath
        if ev.state == MAIN_DISPATCHER:
            if not datapath.id in self.datapaths:
                self.logger.debug('register datapath: %016x', datapath.id)
                self.datapaths[datapath.id] = datapath
        elif ev.state == DEAD_DISPATCHER:
            if datapath.id in self.datapaths:
                self.logger.debug('unregister datapath: %016x', datapath.id)
                del self.datapaths[datapath.id]

    def _monitor(self):
        while True:
            for dp in self.datapaths.values():
                self._request_stats(dp)
            hub.sleep(10)

    def _request_stats(self, datapath):
        self.logger.debug('send stats request: %016x', datapath.id)
        ofproto = datapath.ofproto
        parser = datapath.ofproto_parser

        req = parser.OFPFlowStatsRequest(datapath)
        datapath.send_msg(req)

        req = parser.OFPPortStatsRequest(datapath, 0, ofproto.OFPP_ANY)
        datapath.send_msg(req)

    @set_ev_cls(ofp_event.EventOFPFlowStatsReply, MAIN_DISPATCHER)
    def _flow_stats_reply_handler(self, ev):
        body = ev.msg.body

        self.logger.info('datapath         '

                         'in-port  eth-dst           '
                         'out-port packets  bytes')
        self.logger.info('---------------- '
                         '-------- ----------------- '
                         '-------- -------- --------')

        for stat in sorted([flow for flow in body if flow.priority == 1],
                          key=lambda flow: (flow.match['in_port'],
                                            flow.match['eth_dst'])):
#            self.logger.info('%016x %8x %17s %8x %8d %8d',
               if stat.match['in_port']==1:
                    self.logger.info('%x %x %s %x %d %d',
                             ev.msg.datapath.id,
                             stat.match['in_port'], stat.match['eth_dst'],
                             stat.instructions[0].actions[0].port,
                             stat.packet_count, stat.byte_count)

        #for stat in [1234]#sorted([flow for flow in body if flow.priority == 1],
                         # key=lambda flow: (flow.match['in_port'],
                                #            flow.match['eth_dst'])):
#            self.logger.info('%016x %8x %17s %8x %8d %8d',
              # if stat.match['in_port']==1:
                  #  self.logger.info('%x %x %s %x %d %d',
                   #          ev.msg.datapath.id,
                   #          stat.match['in_port'], stat.match['eth_dst'],
                   #          stat.instructions[0].actions[0].port,
                   #          stat.packet_count, stat.byte_count)

    @set_ev_cls(ofp_event.EventOFPPortStatsReply, MAIN_DISPATCHER)
    def _port_stats_reply_handler(self, ev):
        body = ev.msg.body

        self.logger.info('datapath         port     '
                         'rx-pkts  rx-bytes rx-error '
                         'tx-pkts  tx-bytes tx-error')
        self.logger.info('---------------- -------- '
                         '-------- -------- -------- '
                         '-------- -------- --------')
        for stat in sorted(body, key=attrgetter('port_no')):
            if stat.port_no==1:

                 self.logger.info('%016x %8x %8d %8d %8d %8d %8d %8d', 
                             ev.msg.datapath.id, stat.port_no,
                             stat.rx_packets, stat.rx_bytes, stat.rx_errors,
                             stat.tx_packets, stat.tx_bytes, stat.tx_errors)
```

Please help me edit this code to answer my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add two method in your controller:
 1) a method that requests stats
 2) a method that captures the answers from switches.

The method for answering stats is the following:

```
def send_flow_stats_request(self, datapath):
    ofp = datapath.ofproto
    ofp_parser = datapath.ofproto_parser
cookie = cookie_mask = 0
match = ofp_parser.OFPMatch(in_port=1)
req = ofp_parser.OFPFlowStatsRequest(datapath, 0,
                                     ofp.OFPTT_ALL,
                                     ofp.OFPP_ANY, ofp.OFPG_ANY,
                                     cookie, cookie_mask,
                                     match)
datapath.send_msg(req)
```

The method for capturing answers is this one:

```
@set_ev_cls(ofp_event.EventOFPFlowStatsReply, MAIN_DISPATCHER)
def flow_stats_reply_handler(self, ev):
    flows = []
    for stat in ev.msg.body:
        flows.append('table_id=%s '
                     'duration_sec=%d duration_nsec=%d '
                     'priority=%d '
                     'idle_timeout=%d hard_timeout=%d flags=0x%04x '
                     'cookie=%d packet_count=%d byte_count=%d '
                     'match=%s instructions=%s' %
                     (stat.table_id,
                      stat.duration_sec, stat.duration_nsec,
                      stat.priority,
                      stat.idle_timeout, stat.hard_timeout, stat.flags,
                      stat.cookie, stat.packet_count, stat.byte_count,
                      stat.match, stat.instructions))
    self.logger.debug('FlowStats: %s', flows)
```

Once you capture stats you can compute bandwidth usage.

However you have also other kind of requests you can perform so i suggest you to read the rye doc.

http://ryu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/